# Plot an elliptic curve in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I am trying to plot the elliptic curve secp256k1 y^2=x^3+7 in my latex-document.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:4, samples at ={-1.769292354238631, -1.76, -1.74, ..., 2.26, 2.35, 2.7, 2.9}]
    \draw[->] (-2.2,0) -- (3.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-2.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[->, color=red] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x^3+7)}) node[right] {$y^2=x^3-2x+2$};
    \draw[->, color=red] plot (\x,{-sqrt(\x^3+7)}) node[right] {}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

but this gives me a curve that is interrupted at the left.
And to be honest, I don't really know what all of these comments mean.

I would be happy if someone could help me, or has a good tutorial that explains how the plotting in Latex works!

Thanks in advance! And all the best.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately you didn't provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Do I assume right, that you mean with "comments" the LOG file? Because you missed a `;` at the end of the last `\draw` command.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, could you consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673525/how-to-draw-an-an-elliptic-curve-such-as-y2-x3-x-with-tikz

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution that really uses PGFPlots. There you would get a very similar result as you did, when you wouldn't set the minimum x value (of the `domain`) manually.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.12,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-7,
            ymax=7,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            scale only axis,
            axis lines=middle,
            % set the minimum value to the minimum x value
            % which in this case is $-\sqrt[3]{7}$
            domain=-1.912931:3,      % <-- works for pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
%            domain=-1.91293118:3,   % <-- would also work for LuaLaTeX
            samples=200,
            smooth,
            % to avoid that the "plot node" is clipped (partially)
            clip=false,
            % use same unit vectors on the axis
            axis equal image=true,
        ]
            \addplot [red] {sqrt(x^3+7)}
                node[right] {$y^2=x^3+7$};
            \addplot [red] {-sqrt(x^3+7)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I'm not sure the picture is right.

Comment: @egreg, I think you skepticism came from the scaling of the axis. I edited my answer to use the same unit vector on both axis.

Comment: It wasn't the plot of `y^2 = x` because it was clipped.

Comment: @StefanPinnow The equation of the curve was wrongly printed

Comment: @egreg, sorry, I think I don't understand your point. When you agree that the actual image is right, then also the "old" one was right, because the only (important) thing I changed was adding the option `axis equal image=true`. So when you comment that line or set the value to `false` you will get the "old" image (again) ...

Comment: The previous picture had just `y^2=x`, not `y^2=x^3+7`

Comment: @egreg, oh sorry. Seems I didn't get the sentence right. Of course just the node was clipped partially ... Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: when I try to use this I still get a weird curve that is open at the left side...
the documentclass "standalone" did not work for me. Could that be the reason? (All the rest I copied from the above).

Comment: @Luca, I think this is a (math) precision issue. I assume you have compiled using pdfLaTeX, right? (I used LuaLaTeX.) If so, delete some figures from the lower bound value of `domain` until the curve is "closed" again.

Comment: Thank you @StefanPinnow ! But what does this mean? What does domain do?

Comment: From the PGFPlots manual you will see that `domain` specifies the x range in which the given expression/formula is evaluated (using the number of `samples` given). That is, when you state `\addplot [mark=*,domain=0:2,samples=3] {1};` you will get points at x values 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: It does not work well for $y^2 = x^3 - 3x + 1$, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have no objection using `pstricks`, it's very simple to plot:

```
\documentclass[11pt,x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\def\f{sqrt(x^3 + 7)}

\begin{document}

\psset{plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, algebraic, arrowinset=0.12}%
\begin{pspicture*}(-5.8,-6.5)(6,7)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, ticksize=-2pt 2pt, labels =none, arrows=->, ](0,0)(-5.8,-6.5)(6,7)[$x$, -120][$y$, -135]
    \uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}\uput[dl](-1.913,0){ $ -\sqrt[3]{7} $}
    \uput[dl](0,-2.65 ){$ -\sqrt{7}$} \uput[ul](0,2.65 ){$ \sqrt{7}$}
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=IndianRed3}
    \psplot{-1.91293}{5}{\f}
    \psplot{-1.91293}{5}{-\f}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}]
```

[image]

*Note:*
 This code is compilable with `pdflatex` if you launch it with the `-shell-escape` switch (under TeX Live or MacTeX), or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX). Alternatively, remove the `auto-pst-pdf` package, and compile with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1):

Plotted as `y^2-x^3-7=0`. Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-3,-6.5)(6,7)
\psaxes[labels=none,arrows=->,linecolor=black!50](0,0)(-3,-6.5)(6,7)[$x$, -120][$y$,-135]
\uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}\uput[dl](-1.913,0){ $ -\sqrt[3]{7} $}
\uput[dl](0,-2.65 ){$ -\sqrt{7}$} \uput[ul](0,2.65 ){$ \sqrt{7}$}
\psplotImp[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red!60,algebraic](-4,-8)(6,8){y^2 - x^3 - 7}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]