# Plot y^2=x^3+7 in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, plot, domain

My question refers to this post:
[Plot an elliptic curve in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341063/plot-an-elliptic-curve-in-latex/341112?noredirect=1#comment837204_341112)
I hope it is not too similar, but the answers in this questions did not work for me.
I am trying to plot this in Latex [image]

But when I try this with the code from the answers in question "Plot an elliptic curve in Latex" I keep getting a curve that is open on the left side.

I am working with Texmaker and want to include this plot in a documentclass

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,british,openright]{book}
```

I would be really happy if someone could tell me my mistake when implementing this for Latex, or a way how to do it right.

In a comment someone told me to change the "domain" part. But I don't know what this part is doing for my plot, and so in the end it gets quite messy.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=4,
        ymin=-7,
        ymax=7,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        % set the minimum value to the minimum x value
        % which in this case is $-\sqrt[3]{7}$
        domain=-2.646:4,
        samples=200,
        smooth,
        % to avoid that the "plot node" is clipped (partially)
        clip=false,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]
        \addplot [red] {sqrt(x^3+7)}
            node[right] {$y^2=x^3+7$};
        \addplot [red] {-sqrt(x^3+7)};
        \draw[color=blue] (-4, 0) node[left] {$\bullet$};
        \draw[color=blue] (-1.71, 1.4) node[left] {$P_1$};
        \draw[color=blue] (-1.71, 1.4) node[left] {$\bullet$};
        \draw[color=blue] (0.33,2.65) node[left] {$P_2$};
        \draw[color=blue] (0.33,2.65) node[left] {$\bullet$};
        \draw[color=blue] (1.76, 3.53) node[left] {$R$};
        \draw[color=blue] (1.76, 3.53) node[left] {$\bullet$};
        \draw[color=blue] (1.76, -3.53) node[left] {$P_3 = P_1+P_2$};
        \draw[color=blue] (1.76, -3.53) node[left] {$\bullet$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(This is one of my many tries to make it work.)
It looks like this:
[image]

I would be really thankfull if someone could help me with this.

All the best,

Luca

Comment: What do you mean with ‘the curve is open, on the left side’?

Comment: the two plots sqrt(x^3+7) and -sqrt(x^3+7) don't "touch" at the x-axis.

Comment: I don't know well TiKZ. Did you try the pstricks solution?

Comment: i added a picture :)

Comment: i really don't know anything about plotting in latex... what is pstricks?

Comment: Another group of packages (different from TiKZ), which relies on `postscript` (Adobe's page description programming language) to plot graphics. For LaTeX users, it's easier to learn than TiKZ, in my opinion, because it uses LaTeX commands. Of the two answers to the above-mentioned questions, mine was based on pstricks. Did you try to compile its code?

Comment: @Bernard: Why are you suggesting a different drawing package?

Comment: Recalculate your cube root of 7 (-7^(1/3) does work in my installation), then it works fine for me (you might need to increase the number of samples. Or at least the hole is smaller.

Comment: I do not ‘suggest’, I recall there are different drawing packages, and gave *my* opinion as to learning easiness, that's all.

Comment: @Bernard yes, i also tried your solution, but it gave me an error... it sais "I can't find file 'pst-arrow'. And I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @daleif thanks for the comment, but where do you mean I should recalculate the cube root of 7? What does "samples" do?

Comment: You set the domain, the first value is not -\sqrt[3]{7}

Comment: ohhh ok! thank you! Do you know why the points are not on the curve? I took them from my geogebra solution... is there a better way?

Comment: I've seen this before, and there is an answer to this somewhere on the site, just cannot remember at present.

Comment: @Luca: `pstricks-add` has recently been split into a new `pstricks-add` and `pst-arrow`. This means you should update your distribution.

Comment: @Bernard how can I do that?  (I googled it, but didn't find how this is done..)

Comment: @Luca: this depends on your distribution. MiKTeX uses MiKTeX Package Manager to install newpackages, and MiKTeX Update to update the installed files. TeX Live uses Tlmgr, or TeX Live utilities on a MacOS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already was stated in the comments below the question by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341409/plot-y2-x37-in-latex#comment837900_341409) and in the answer of [Johannes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341502/95441) the curve isn't "closed" because you have used the wrong `domain` starting point.

(Interesting that you have used [*my* answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341112/95441) from the corresponding question, but for whatever reason changed the `domain` starting point to `-2.646` ... We also already discussed that in the comments below that answer.)

For the second point: Your marks are not drawn where you expect them, because you first state a coordinate and then say, that a node should be drawn *`[left]`* of the specified coordinate with *a `$\bullet$` as text*.

Have a look at the comments of code for more details on how this works.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % `calc' library used for the line from (P0) through (P3)
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % define the style `point' which is used for the nodes on the coordinates
        point/.style={
            circle,
            fill=blue,
            inner sep=1.5pt,
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4.5,
            xmax=4,
            ymin=-7,
            ymax=7,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            scale only axis,
            axis lines=middle,
            % set the minimum value to the minimum x value
            % which in this case is $-\sqrt[3]{7}$
            domain=-1.912931:3,
            samples=200,
            smooth,
            % to avoid that the "plot node" is clipped (partially)
            clip=false,
            % use same unit vectors on the axis
            axis equal image=true,
        ]
            \addplot [red] {sqrt(x^3+7)}
                node[right] {$y^2=x^3+7$};
            \addplot [red] {-sqrt(x^3+7)};

            % add nodes to the points and the corresponding labels
            \node [point]
                (P0) at (-4,0)       {};
            \node [point,label={left:$P_1$}]
                (P1) at (-1.71,1.4)  {};
            \node [point,label={above:$P_2$}]
                (P2) at (0.33,2.65)  {};
            \node [point,label={right:$P_3 = P_1 + P_2$}]
                (P3) at (1.76,3.53)  {};
            \node [point,label={right:$R$}]
                (R)  at (1.76,-3.53) {};

            % draw a line from (P0) a bit further than just to (P3)
            \draw [blue] (P0) -- ($ (P0)!1.1!(P3) $);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thank you both very much! I really had no clue what I was doing and tried all different numbers for the domain :D
Again, thanks a lot to both of you!!

Answer (score 5):

With `domain=<x1>:<x2>` and `samples=<num>` you specify at which points `pgfplots` evaluates your function.
The plot would therefore start at the x-axis only if such a data point would coincidentally be the root of the function.

The naive solution would be to increase the number of samples to a ridiculous amount and just hope for the best.
A more clever way is to compute the root by hand (as daleif already suggested) and specify the domain accordingly.

---

**Edit:** Since Stefan has already addressed the issue with your node labels, I just want to show you another way to compute the intersections (which does not seem to work with the `smooth` option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-4.5,xmax=4,ymin=-7,ymax=7,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    scale only axis,axis lines=middle,
    samples=200,%smooth,
    clip=false,axis equal image=true
  ]
    \addplot [red,domain=-1.91293:4,name path=CurveA] {sqrt(x^3+7)};
    \addplot [red,domain=-1.91293:4,name path=CurveB] {-sqrt(x^3+7)};
    \path [name path=LineA] (-4,0) -- (4,4.90);
    \path [name path=LineB] (-4,0) -- (4,-4.90);
    \fill [blue,name intersections={of=CurveA and LineA}]
      (intersection-1) circle (2pt) node [above left] {$P_1$}
      (intersection-2) circle (2pt) node [below right] {$P_2$}
      (intersection-3) circle (2pt) node [below right] {$R$};
    \path [blue,name intersections={of=CurveB and LineB}];
    \fill [blue] (intersection-3) circle (2pt)
      node [above right] {$P_3 = P_1 + P_2$};
    \fill [blue] (-4,0) circle (2pt);
    \fill [blue] (-4,0) circle (2pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahh, so 1.91293 is more precise than `7^(1/3)`

Comment: ok, thank you already for this solution! Can you also help me with the points? Why don't they fit in Latex but do so in my other plotting program? (pictures)