# How to graph this equation

Tags: pgfplots

How do I graph this equation in PGF-TikZ:

`x^2+((96*y/69)-(sqrt(abs(x))))^2=1`

using `\usepackage{pgf,tikz}`?

EDIT: What about this one:

`-2(x^2)-2(y^4)+3(y^3)+2(y^2)-(2*(x^2)*(y^2))+(x/3)=0`

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341409/plot-y2-x37-in-latex, the answers to that question show how to plot a similar function.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The first one is a simple quadratic equation which can be [solved on paper](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2%2B((96*y%2F69)-(sqrt(abs(x))))%5E2%3D1+for+y) easily with the two solutions

[image]

This can then be graphed using `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=101,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    ]
    \addplot {23/32*(sqrt(abs(x)) - sqrt(1-x^2))};
    \addplot {23/32*(sqrt(abs(x)) + sqrt(1-x^2))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For equations like the one in the comments the approach is the following:

1. Rewrite the equation to isolate zero on the left-hand side.
2. Plug the resulting right-hand side into a contour plot.
3. To solve the equation, instruct `gnuplot` to plot the contour at level 0.

Also set `labels=false`, otherwise the resulting line will be annotated with 0 everywhere.  Since you are calling an external program (`gnuplot`) you have to use `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90},
      samples=101,
      no markers,
    ]

    \addplot3+[
      contour gnuplot={
        levels=0,
        labels=false,
      }
    ]
    {-2*(x^2)-2*(y^4)+3*(y^3)+2*(y^2)-(2*(x^2)*(y^2))+(x/3)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't your two solutions the same?

Comment: @manthano Yes, sorry.  I corrected it.

Comment: @HenriMenke What about this one: -2(x^2)-2(y^4)+3(y^3)+2(y^2)-(2*(x^2)*(y^2))+(x/3)=0

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan See updated answer.

Comment: I guess you're doing the OP's homework?

Comment: @cfr Why don’t we have a homework tag on TeX.SX?  Math and Physics have one.

Comment: @HenriMenke I got this error after running your code: 

! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{test_contourtmp0.table} could not be
opened.

Comment: I don't know. Why? Does it help? I guess its intention would be unclear. I don't think we should do people's homework for them, but others apparently disagree. I get the impression there is more of a consensus on maths, at least.